# Cannot connect to hyper-v server

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

When I attempt to connect to my Hyper-V server i receive this message

"This version of Virtual Machine Connection cannot be used to manage servers running Hyper-V in Windows Server 2012 and earlier versions" Image just in case - http://puu.sh/ca6i3/e6b926ce2e.png

If I cannot connect to my Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V using windows 8.1, what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

Found my fix.

Windows 8.1 Hyper-V Installs 2 different connection executable, one located in "C:\Program Files\Hyper-V\6.2"

and another located in "C:\Windows\System32\vmconnect.exe"

One version is from windows 8, while the other version is from windows 8.1.

Manually executing the one within the Hyper-V directory fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue on Windows 10 - same solution as found by theruss0n (thanks!) but this time the path is "C:\Program Files\Hyper-V\6.3\vmconnect6.3.exe"